# After migration to struts 2.3.24, file upload still not supported for greater than 2gb

Tags: java, file-upload, struts2, multipartform-data, max-size

Adding the following the to struts.xml in struts2.3.24:

```xml
<constant name="struts.multipart.parser"  value="jakarta-stream" />
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="3147483648" />
```

For reference the upload works as follows in the jsp:

```xml
<s:form id="uploadData" action="abc_UploadAction?method=Upload" namespace="xyz"   validateFields="false" method="post"    enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

For action mapping we use the concept of DMI. The action configuration is as follows:

```xml
<action name="abc_*" class="ABCAction">
<result type="chain">invoke_${module}_{1}_${method}</result>
</action>
```

But file upload still not working for large files of greater than 2gb. But the above code works fine for lesser size uploads,

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/q/2947683/1700321.

Comment: @AleksandrM as far as I've understood, he's able to upload 1.9GB files, but not 2.1GB giles... the 2MB file limit should've been hit before, I guess (but it's worth a try, maybe hes' trying with 1MB and 2.1GB)

Comment: @Aleksandr, We have already configured (for size limits greater than 2 gb ) the server.xml and web.xml as mentioned in this post.

Comment: @Andrea, Your understanding is correct. The file upload is successful for upto 2gb but fails for anything over it i.e, over 2 gb.

Comment: OK. You haven't mentioned this before.

Comment: No the action method referred in the s:form is not being referenced.

Comment: So what is happening when the file size is larger than 2gb? What do you see? Any exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you declaring a bean, if [the documentation](https://struts.apache.org/docs/file-upload.html) is not telling you to do so ?

Just change

```xml
<bean type="org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.MultiPartRequest" name="jakartaStream"
     class="org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.JakartaStreamMultiPartRequest" 
     scope="default" />
<constant name="struts.multipart.parser"  value="jakartaStream" />
```

to the right configuration that should be (hyphenized, not capitalized):

```xml
<constant name="struts.multipart.parser"  value="jakarta-stream" />
```

Comment: Thanks for  your answer. I have made the above changes but even then the file uploads more than 2 gb are not successful.

Comment: please post the list of the jars you're using

Comment: P.S: I've seen now your code is from the JIRA, btw it's not needed anymore to declare the bean, since it's been put in the struts core from 2.3.18

Comment: List of jars: struts2-core-2.3.24 struts2-dojo-plugin-2.3.24 struts2-json-plugin-2.3.24 xwork-core-2.3.24 commons-io-2.2 freemarker-2.3.22 asm-tree-3.3 asm-commons-3.3 asm-3.3 log4j-1.2.17 ognl-3.0.6 javassist-3.11.0.GA commons-lang3-3.2 commons-fileupload-1.3.1 commons-logging-1.1.3. Yes have removed the bean on your advice and it works fine for less than 2 gb uploads but still not working for greater than 2gb uploads

Comment: They're fine. Are you extending struts-default in your package ? Do you see any error in server / app logs ? Also show your action configuration

Comment: Yes we extend struts-default,json-default in our package. No error in server or app logs is obtained. Just that the uploading gives no response for greater than 2 gb file uploads. For action configuration details I have updated the code details in the question. Please refer.

Comment: Can you show the content of the action that is uploading the file ? Also, try not using chain that is discouraged :/

Comment: It is just that the form action refers to method  Upload of the class UploadAction.java . In this method we have the business logic for file upload.

Comment: I know, I've asked you the action definition to check if there were problems with the interceptor stack configuration, and now I'm asking you the action code to check if there are problems with the variables involved in the upload... the file and the two strings with filename and contenttype. Everything seems fine until now, I'm just shooting in the dark if can't see the code

Comment: @ Andrea,the code does not reach upto there. It is only in the POST phase after which the content type and filename are to be determined. But     I have made all necessary configuration for Tomcat. The request is not forwarded from there itself. Any idea on probable reason??

Comment: Between the JSP post and the action method there is a stack of interceptors. If the action is not reached, then the flow has been interrupted in some interceptor. You need to put devMode constant to true, and report here the exception, error message, warning message or whatever is printed in the logs that explain what is happening and where